# How to hidden (read) output in Common Lisp

Tags: emacs, lisp, common-lisp, sbcl, slime

I am writing a password input function, I would make it like Unix/Linux password input style, input but without print anything on the screen. Or, print "*" on the screen is fine too.

I found this question "[common lisp, how to mask keyboard input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39797560/common-lisp-how-to-mask-keyboard-input)", it is what I want, but the functions answer given `echo-on` and `echo-off` give me panic when I run them in my slime. (However, they passed compiling).

I code in emacs/slime, and the panic happens in slime (error messages below). In my plan, I will run this single script in the terminal by `sbcl --load ./this-script.lisp`.

The error message is:

```
#<TWO-WAY-STREAM
  :INPUT-STREAM #<SB-SYS:FD-STREAM for "standard input" {1004AA8933}>
  :OUTPUT-STREAM #<SB-SYS:FD-STREAM for "standard output" {1004AA8A63}>>
    fell through ETYPECASE expression.
Wanted one of (FILE-STREAM FIXNUM).
   [Condition of type SB-KERNEL:CASE-FAILURE]
```

Does anyone know how to make it now?

Thank you.

sbcl version: SBCL 2.0.0
macOS: 10.15.2

Comment: you need to tell us how you are using it? in a terminal, in an emacs/slime in a terminal, in some GUI, ....  each one of these might use different methods to display things.

Comment: Sorry about it. I just add the way I run it.

Comment: The error messages says that the code expected a fixnum or a file-stream, but a two-way-stream is not a file-stream (Slime rebinds input/output streams, that's why there is a two-way stream). But "sb-sys:*tty*" should not be impacted, so I guess it should also fails if you remove Slime out of the problem? Did you try running the script in a terminal directly (ie. `sbcl --load ...`)?

Comment: I just tried, you are right, `sbcl —load` works fine. So do I have any way to run it in slime? Or don’t run echo-off/on when it running in slime? Thank you.

Comment: I use `#-swank` to detect the running env. If in slime, do not run echo-on/off. Are there any better ways.

Answer (score 1):

If you run `slime` directly from emacs (even if emacs is started with `-nw`), there is no terminal to control with [termios](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/termios.h.html). In that case `sb-sys:*tty*` is bound to a two-way stream that is neither a `file-stream` nor a `fixnum`. That's why the code fails.

If your code should be able to run within different user interfaces (actual emacs GUI, GTK, etc.), then you need to manage the front-end and dedicated ways to prompt for a password (e.g. emacs has a `read-passwd` function, but you have to call emacs code from sbcl, which by default is forbidden; and the password should probably be encrypted during transport between emacs and sbcl); this is a lot more work, and there is no easy answer.

If you only want to write an application that is supposed to run exclusively in a terminal, but during development you want to code from emacs using Slime, then you can simply change how you start Slime:

- Start sbcl from a terminal
- Run a swank server

  ```
  (ql:quickload :swank)
  (swank:create-server)
  ```
- From emacs, use `slime-connect` to connect to that server

Then, `sb-sys:*tty*` will designate the terminal, and the code should work as intended. The same code runs in all cases (development and actual usage).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I compared `slime` and `sbcl` `features` list and find only slime has `swank`. So I use #-swank to avoid `echo-on/off` function in slime. It works. And I think it might be the easiest way to make this feature.

Comment: @ccQpein I'd say that "swank" being present in your image (even if not used) is unrelated from sbcl being run from a terminal; so if might fix your problem, but only  by chance. A more robust approach would be to handle `(echo off)`, and call `(echo on)` on exit only when the previous `(echo off)` succeded (?)